# Bootstrap Collapse element on a scroll event

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, custom-data-attribute

I am developing an Angular application and am using Bootstrap 5.2.
I am using the [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/) component on a card and it works perfectly using the data attributes.

However, I want to trigger the collapse on a scroll event, currently I have the card fixed at the top of the screen and when the user starts scrolling I want the card's body to collapse. I was able to get this working by instantiating the collapse on the element using Typescript and removed the data attributes and toggled the collapse on a click as well using Typescript.

This solution however imposed unwanted side effects such as offcanvas items still having a faded background when clicking away and dropdown elements not popping up when clicked.

This is how I instantiated the Collapse on the card's body

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.target = document.getElementById('targetID');
    this.collapse = new Collapse(this.target, { toggle: false });
}
```

Here I am detecting srcoll changes and if the user has scrolled down by 50px then it triggers the collapse to hide otherwise it must show.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.scrollEvent && changes.scrollEvent.currentValue !== changes.scrollEvent.previousValue) {
        this.show = this.scrollEvent.target.scrollTop <= 50;

        if (this.collapse) {
            if (this.show) {
                this.collapse.show();
            } else {
                this.collapse.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML element I am collapsing, it should show by default.

```
<div class="collapse show" id="targetID">
    <div class="card-body rounded bg-white p-1">
        ...content...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong that is causing other bootstrap elements to work incorrectly? Or is there a way to toggle a collapse element with data attributes on a scroll event?

Comment: `ngOnChanges` triggers [whenever a data-bound property changes.](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) How do you think this relates to the scroll position?

Comment: Oh yes I should probably mention, the scrollevents are on the parent component and passed as in input to this component so I am using `ngOnChanges` to detect changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, it seems the project I was working on had bootstrap imported vis `angular.json` and in `styles.scss`. This caused a conflicting issue with popper which is now resolved by only importing bootstrap in `styles.scss`